# How might I change the Form loading at start-up to another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

By default when I run my project, it loads `form1`, but I want to change it such that when it loads the Project it opens `form2` instead. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 9):

Go to your Program.cs file and change the form class:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Change to:

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```